# OSError when importing pims python 3.7

Tags: python, windows, image-processing, dll

the first time I import pims appears this message

`import pims`

---

```
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-c035db68c7c1> in <module>
----> 1 import pims

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pims\__init__.py in <module>
----> 1 from pims.api import *
      2 
      3 from ._version import get_versions
      4 __version__ = get_versions()['version']
      5 del get_versions

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pims\api.py in <module>
    110 
    111 try:
--> 112     from pims_nd2 import ND2_Reader
    113 except ImportError:
    114     ND2_Reader = not_available("pims_nd2")

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pims_nd2\__init__.py in <module>
----> 1 from .nd2reader import ND2_Reader

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pims_nd2\nd2reader.py in <module>
      6 from pims.base_frames import FramesSequenceND
      7 import os
----> 8 from . import ND2SDK as h
      9 from ctypes import c_uint8, c_uint16, c_float
     10 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pims_nd2\ND2SDK.py in <module>
     21        raise OSError("The bitsize does not equal 32 or 64.")
     22     os.environ["PATH"] += os.pathsep + os.path.join(dlldir)
---> 23     nd2 = cdll.LoadLibrary('v6_w32_nd2ReadSDK.dll')
     24 
     25 

~\Anaconda3\lib\ctypes\__init__.py in LoadLibrary(self, name)
    440 
    441     def LoadLibrary(self, name):
--> 442         return self._dlltype(name)
    443 
    444 cdll = LibraryLoader(CDLL)

~\Anaconda3\lib\ctypes\__init__.py in __init__(self, name, mode, handle, use_errno, use_last_error)
    362 
    363         if handle is None:
--> 364             self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
    365         else:
    366             self._handle = handle

OSError: [WinError 14001] No se pudo iniciar la aplicación; la configuración en paralelo no es correcta. Consulte el registro de eventos de la aplicación o use la herramienta sxstrace.exe de la línea de comandos para obtener más detalles
```

Then, when I try to import again this other error message appears

`import pims`

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-c035db68c7c1> in <module>
----> 1 import pims

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pims\__init__.py in <module>
----> 1 from pims.api import *
      2 
      3 from ._version import get_versions
      4 __version__ = get_versions()['version']
      5 del get_versions

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pims\api.py in <module>
     34 try:
     35     import pims.pyav_reader
---> 36     if pims.pyav_reader.available():
     37         PyAVReaderTimed = pims.pyav_reader.PyAVReaderTimed
     38         PyAVReaderIndexed = pims.pyav_reader.PyAVReaderIndexed

AttributeError: module 'pims' has no attribute 'pyav_reader'
```

Windows Event manager show this error

> Error al generar el contexto de activación para
>   "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pims_nd2\ND2SDK\win\x64\v6_gnr_picture.dll".
>   No se encontró el ensamblado dependiente
>   Microsoft.VC90.OpenMP,processorArchitecture="amd64",publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b",type="win32",version="9.0.21022.8".
>   Use sxstrace.exe para obtener un diagnóstico detallado.

#### edit: english error and traceback, taken from [here](https://forum.image.sc/t/open-nd2-files-in-python-with-nd2reader-3-1-0/25637/6):

> ```
> OSError Traceback (most recent call last)
> in
> ----> 1 import pims
>
> ~\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\pyPIMS\Lib\site-packages\pims_init_.py
> in
> ----> 1 from pims.api import *
> 2
> 3 from ._version import get_versions
> 4 version = get_versions()[‘version’]
> 5 del get_versions
>
> ~\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\pyPIMS\Lib\site-packages\pims\api.py
> in
> 110
> 111 try:
> –> 112 from pims_nd2 import ND2_Reader
> 113 except ImportError:
> 114 ND2_Reader = not_available(“pims_nd2”)
>
> ~\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\pyPIMS\Lib\site-packages\pims_nd2_init_.py
> in
> ----> 1 from .nd2reader import ND2_Reader
>
> ~\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\pyPIMS\Lib\site-packages\pims_nd2\nd2reader.py
> in
> 6 from pims.base_frames import FramesSequenceND
> 7 import os
> ----> 8 from . import ND2SDK as h
> 9 from ctypes import c_uint8, c_uint16, c_float
> 10
>
> ~\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\pyPIMS\Lib\site-packages\pims_nd2\ND2SDK.py
> in
> 21 raise OSError(“The bitsize does not equal 32 or 64.”)
> 22 os.environ[“PATH”] += os.pathsep + os.path.join(dlldir)
> —> 23 nd2 = cdll.LoadLibrary(‘v6_w32_nd2ReadSDK.dll’)
> 24
> 25
>
> C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\ctypes_init_.py in LoadLibrary(self, name)
> 432
> 433 def LoadLibrary(self, name):
> –> 434 return self._dlltype(name)
> 435
> 436 cdll = LibraryLoader(CDLL)
>
> C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\ctypes_init_.py in init(self, name, mode, handle, use_errno, use_last_error)
> 354
> 355 if handle is None:
> –> 356 self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
> 357 else:
> 358 self._handle = handle
>
> OSError: [WinError 14001] The application has failed to start because its side-by-side configuration is incorrect. Please see the
> application event log or use the command-line sxstrace.exe tool for
> more detail
> ```

I´m adding the sxstrace.exe report (I have extracted the part of the report that contains the error, I guess)

```
=================
Iniciar generación de contexto de activación.
Parámetro de entrada:
    Flags = 0
    ProcessorArchitecture = AMD64
    CultureFallBacks = es-MX;es;es-ES;en-US;en
    ManifestPath = C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\envs\spyder4\lib\site-packages\pims_nd2\ND2SDK\win\x64\v6_gnr_system.dll
    AssemblyDirectory = C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\envs\spyder4\lib\site-packages\pims_nd2\ND2SDK\win\x64\
    Application Config File = 
-----------------
INFORMACIÓN: analizando archivo de manifiesto C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\envs\spyder4\lib\site-packages\pims_nd2\ND2SDK\win\x64\v6_gnr_system.dll.
    INFORMACIÓN: la identidad de definición del manifiesto es (null).
    INFORMACIÓN: referencia: Microsoft.VC90.CRT,processorArchitecture="amd64",publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b",type="win32",version="9.0.21022.8"
    INFORMACIÓN: referencia: Microsoft.VC90.OpenMP,processorArchitecture="amd64",publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b",type="win32",version="9.0.21022.8"
INFORMACIÓN: resolviendo referencia Microsoft.VC90.CRT,processorArchitecture="amd64",publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b",type="win32",version="9.0.21022.8".
    INFORMACIÓN: resolviendo referencia de ProcessorArchitecture amd64.
        INFORMACIÓN: resolviendo referencia cultural Neutral.
            INFORMACIÓN: aplicando directiva de enlace.
                INFORMACIÓN: buscar directiva de edición en C:\WINDOWS\WinSxS\manifests\amd64_policy.9.0.microsoft.vc90.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.9619_none_accdd623e1ddaffe.manifest
                INFORMACIÓN: versión de ensamblado redirigida por directiva de edición.
                INFORMACIÓN: la identidad de la directiva de publicación es Microsoft.VC90.CRT,processorArchitecture="amd64",publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b",type="win32",version="9.0.30729.9619".
            INFORMACIÓN: iniciar sondeo de ensamblado.
                INFORMACIÓN: intento de sondear manifiesto en C:\WINDOWS\WinSxS\manifests\amd64_microsoft.vc90.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.9619_none_08e065a3a84109b0.manifest.
                INFORMACIÓN: manifiesto encontrado en C:\WINDOWS\WinSxS\manifests\amd64_microsoft.vc90.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.9619_none_08e065a3a84109b0.manifest.
            INFORMACIÓN: finalizar sondeo de ensamblado.
INFORMACIÓN: resolviendo referencia Microsoft.VC90.CRT.mui,language="&#x2a;",processorArchitecture="amd64",publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b",type="win32",version="9.0.30729.9619".
    INFORMACIÓN: resolviendo referencia de ProcessorArchitecture amd64.
        INFORMACIÓN: resolviendo referencia cultural es-MX.
            INFORMACIÓN: aplicando directiva de enlace.
                INFORMACIÓN: no se encuentra la directiva de edición.
                INFORMACIÓN: no se encuentra el redirección de la directiva de enlace.
            INFORMACIÓN: iniciar sondeo de ensamblado.
                INFORMACIÓN: no se encontró el ensamblado en WinSxS.
                INFORMACIÓN: intento de sondear manifiesto en C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_64\Microsoft.VC90.CRT.mui\9.0.30729.9619_es-MX_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b\Microsoft.VC90.CRT.mui.DLL.
                INFORMACIÓN: no se encontró el manifiesto de la referencia cultural es-MX.
            INFORMACIÓN: finalizar sondeo de ensamblado.
        INFORMACIÓN: resolviendo referencia cultural es.
            INFORMACIÓN: aplicando directiva de enlace.
                INFORMACIÓN: no se encuentra la directiva de edición.
                INFORMACIÓN: no se encuentra el redirección de la directiva de enlace.
            INFORMACIÓN: iniciar sondeo de ensamblado.
                INFORMACIÓN: no se encontró el ensamblado en WinSxS.
                INFORMACIÓN: intento de sondear manifiesto en C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_64\Microsoft.VC90.CRT.mui\9.0.30729.9619_es_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b\Microsoft.VC90.CRT.mui.DLL.
                INFORMACIÓN: no se encontró el manifiesto de la referencia cultural es.
            INFORMACIÓN: finalizar sondeo de ensamblado.
        INFORMACIÓN: resolviendo referencia cultural es-ES.
            INFORMACIÓN: aplicando directiva de enlace.
                INFORMACIÓN: no se encuentra la directiva de edición.
                INFORMACIÓN: no se encuentra el redirección de la directiva de enlace.
            INFORMACIÓN: iniciar sondeo de ensamblado.
                INFORMACIÓN: no se encontró el ensamblado en WinSxS.
                INFORMACIÓN: intento de sondear manifiesto en C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_64\Microsoft.VC90.CRT.mui\9.0.30729.9619_es-ES_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b\Microsoft.VC90.CRT.mui.DLL.
                INFORMACIÓN: no se encontró el manifiesto de la referencia cultural es-ES.
            INFORMACIÓN: finalizar sondeo de ensamblado.
        INFORMACIÓN: resolviendo referencia cultural en-US.
            INFORMACIÓN: aplicando directiva de enlace.
                INFORMACIÓN: no se encuentra la directiva de edición.
                INFORMACIÓN: no se encuentra el redirección de la directiva de enlace.
            INFORMACIÓN: iniciar sondeo de ensamblado.
                INFORMACIÓN: no se encontró el ensamblado en WinSxS.
                INFORMACIÓN: intento de sondear manifiesto en C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_64\Microsoft.VC90.CRT.mui\9.0.30729.9619_en-US_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b\Microsoft.VC90.CRT.mui.DLL.
                INFORMACIÓN: no se encontró el manifiesto de la referencia cultural en-US.
            INFORMACIÓN: finalizar sondeo de ensamblado.
        INFORMACIÓN: resolviendo referencia cultural en.
            INFORMACIÓN: aplicando directiva de enlace.
                INFORMACIÓN: no se encuentra la directiva de edición.
                INFORMACIÓN: no se encuentra el redirección de la directiva de enlace.
            INFORMACIÓN: iniciar sondeo de ensamblado.
                INFORMACIÓN: no se encontró el ensamblado en WinSxS.
                INFORMACIÓN: intento de sondear manifiesto en C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_64\Microsoft.VC90.CRT.mui\9.0.30729.9619_en_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b\Microsoft.VC90.CRT.mui.DLL.
                INFORMACIÓN: no se encontró el manifiesto de la referencia cultural en.
            INFORMACIÓN: finalizar sondeo de ensamblado.
INFORMACIÓN: resolviendo referencia Microsoft.VC90.OpenMP,processorArchitecture="amd64",publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b",type="win32",version="9.0.21022.8".
    INFORMACIÓN: resolviendo referencia de ProcessorArchitecture amd64.
        INFORMACIÓN: resolviendo referencia cultural Neutral.
            INFORMACIÓN: aplicando directiva de enlace.
                INFORMACIÓN: no se encuentra la directiva de edición.
                INFORMACIÓN: no se encuentra el redirección de la directiva de enlace.
            INFORMACIÓN: iniciar sondeo de ensamblado.
                INFORMACIÓN: no se encontró el ensamblado en WinSxS.
                INFORMACIÓN: intento de sondear manifiesto en C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_64\Microsoft.VC90.OpenMP\9.0.21022.8__1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b\Microsoft.VC90.OpenMP.DLL.
                INFORMACIÓN: intento de sondear manifiesto en C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\envs\spyder4\lib\site-packages\pims_nd2\ND2SDK\win\x64\Microsoft.VC90.OpenMP.DLL.
                INFORMACIÓN: intento de sondear manifiesto en C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\envs\spyder4\lib\site-packages\pims_nd2\ND2SDK\win\x64\Microsoft.VC90.OpenMP.MANIFEST.
                INFORMACIÓN: intento de sondear manifiesto en C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\envs\spyder4\lib\site-packages\pims_nd2\ND2SDK\win\x64\Microsoft.VC90.OpenMP\Microsoft.VC90.OpenMP.DLL.
                INFORMACIÓN: intento de sondear manifiesto en C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\envs\spyder4\lib\site-packages\pims_nd2\ND2SDK\win\x64\Microsoft.VC90.OpenMP\Microsoft.VC90.OpenMP.MANIFEST.
                INFORMACIÓN: no se encontró el manifiesto de la referencia cultural Neutral.
            INFORMACIÓN: finalizar sondeo de ensamblado.
    ERROR: no se puede resolver la referencia Microsoft.VC90.OpenMP,processorArchitecture="amd64",publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b",type="win32",version="9.0.21022.8".
ERROR: error de generación de contexto de activación.
Finalizar generación de contexto de activación.
```

Comment: Can you share the Windows errors in English?... (Windows event and in the first part too)

Comment: I also have this error and have found it to be independent of the python version, but system specific.

Comment: Indeed I´m trying to use pims to open nd2 files, and the problem has to be with the operating system, because in the error appears in my laptop, but not in others from the lab. I have try to uninstall anaconda and reinstalling it and all the packages, but the error persists. Before trying to use pims_nd2 I have installed N2Reader, I don´t know if it is related with the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have **resolved** the problem. It seems to be a missing Visual C++ 2008 file.
I have installed "Actualización de seguridad de MFC para Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Service Pack 1 Redistributable Package" from https://www.microsoft.com/es-ES/download/details.aspx?id=26368
I have downloaded and installed both files: "vcredist_x86.exe" and "vcredist_x64.exe" and After that, pims and pims_nd2 works fine.